# Select data from INFORMATION_SCHEMA query

Tags: mysql, select, information-schema

Probably an easy question..
I've got a list of tables from INFORMATION_SCHEMA and I want to do queries (select, delete etc) on the data within these tables:

I tried

```
Select * from (SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'Col1')
```

But of course it does not work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide the `alias` for the table clause after `FROM` and in `SELECT` like `q.*`

```
SELECT q.* FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'Col1') q
```

All you can see from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is

```
SELECT q.* FROM (SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'id') q
```

But for data you have to reference the `database` with `table` name separately

Comment: This way I'm still selecting the TABLE_NAME, how to select the data within the tables with those names?